# Undefined result when not using callback. Nodejs, Express, and SQL Server Express

Tags: node.js, express, callback, gulp, sql-server-express

The following issue consists of mssql, Nodejs, Gulp, Express, and SQL Server Express. I am able to login to SQL Server Express successfully. However, the returned value is **undefined** when I use the *bookRoute.js code snippet without callback*. Yet, when I use a callback I get the data. However, I don't understand why.

*app.js code snippet:*

```
var config = {
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'Books',
    options: {
       instance: 'SQLEXPRESS'
    }
};

sql.connect(config, function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

*bookRoute.js code snippet without callback:*

```
bookRouter.route('/')
.get(function (req, res) {
    console.log('book router');
    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.query('select * from books').then(
        function (err, recordset) {
            console.log(recordset);
        })
    .catch(function(err){  console.log(err)});
    });
```

*bookRoute.js code snippet with callback:*

```
bookRouter.route('/')
.get(function (req, res) {
    console.log('book router');
    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.query('select * from books',
        function (err, recordset) {
            console.log(recordset);
        });
});
```

Once a user accesses the webpage, then the console should display the results. Unfortunately, the only result that is shown is **undefined** when not using a callback.

*console output:*

```
P:\ub\lic\library>gulp serve
[11:08:28] Using gulpfile P:\ub\lic\library\gulpfile.js
[11:08:28] Starting 'style'...
[11:08:28] Starting 'inject'...
[11:08:53] Finished 'inject' after 808 ms
[11:08:53] Finished 'style' after 25 s
[11:08:53] Starting 'serve'...
[11:08:53] Finished 'serve' after 5.31 ms
[11:08:53] [nodemon] 1.9.2

[11:08:53] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[11:08:53] [nodemon] watching: *.js src/**/*.js
[11:08:53] [nodemon] starting `node app.js`

running server on port 3000
null
book router
undefined
[11:09:21] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
Restarting the server.....beep boop beep beep
[11:09:21] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
Restarting the server.....beep boop beep beep
[11:09:21] [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
running server on port 3000
null
book router
[ { id: 1,
    title: 'A,B,C with Big Bird           ',
    author: 'Michael Jacob ' },
  { id: 2,
    title: 'Peter and his Petunias        ',
    author: 'Jess Holiday  ' },
  { id: 3,
    title: 'The Amazing Average Guy       ',
    author: 'Don Dillon    ' } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> bookRoute.js code snippet without callback:

```
bookRouter.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
console.log('book router');
var request = new sql.Request();
request.query('select * from books')
    .then(function (recordset) {
        console.log(recordset);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

When using bookRoute.js code snippet without callback.The `then` function should have only one argument that is the result from the query that is how it is stated in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql).When there is an error the `catch` function is called.